# Run exe with passing input file in Python

Tags: python, canoe

I wanted to analyse the test report from CANoe. I have an sample exe file from CANoe, where I can pass my vtestreport to the executable file. Once I pass the input file, I can get the verdicts from the report in Command Prompt. This is working in Command Prompt.

Output in Command Prompt

[image: Output in Command Prompt]

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Vector\Test Report Viewer 15 SP4\DataApiSample\DataApiSampleClient\bin\Debug>DataApiSampleClient.exe "C:\Thesis\Test_Report_Viewer\Test.vtestreport"
Test Report "MainPowerSupply" has Verdict Fail
Test Report "MainPowerSupply" contains one or more comments.
Test Report "MainPowerSupply" contains no reassessments.
Last change of annotations on 12/6/2022 2:08:45 PM +01:00.
Traverse tree looking for first failure in a Testcase in Test Report "MainPowerSupply" ...
First failed Testcase: 1. 28199_MainPowerSupply 12V/ 24V - Heating Operation voltage (Ventilation)
First failed activity is a Violation at simulation time 50484.736781
  Title: Measured ' = 0 (Standby), condition: 210 (Ventilation) <= value <= 210 (Ventilation)', Check type: Value Valid
```

But I need to do the same in Python.

My executable file is in this folder:

**C:\Users\Public\Documents\Vector\Test Report Viewer 15 SP4\DataApiSample\DataApiSampleClient\bin\Debug>DataApiSampleClient.exe**

My input file is in this folder:

**C:\Thesis\Test_Report_Viewer\Test.vtestreport**

I tried passing the input file to the exe. But, I'm not able to get the output as it did in Command Prompt. Here is my code.

```py
import subprocess
import os
inputFile = open('C:\Thesis\Test_Report_Viewer\Test.vtestreport','rb') 
output = subprocess.check_output(["C:\Users\Public\Documents\Vector\Test Report Viewer 15 SP4\DataApiSample\DataApiSampleClient\bin\Debug>DataApiSampleClient.exe"], stdin = inputFile) 
inpFile.close()
# outputStr = str(pieOut)[2:-5] #remove garbage
print(output)
```

When I run the above code, I'm encountered with an error.

`SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`

I need get the output in Python as it did in Command Prompt.

Comment: if you post the cmd output as text it would be readable

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with running executables, it's entirely a matter of Python string literal syntax.  To include backslashes in a string, such as a Windows pathname, you either need to double them, prefix the string with `r` to make it a *raw string literal*, or (in many cases) change them to forward slashes.

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for your quick response. I have posted the cmd output in text format.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for your quick response. I will give a try with your comment.

Comment: do the test: `fileName = 'your path'` `print(fileName)` to see what string you pass to `open()` and `\t` is a tab character

Comment: @rioV8 `fileName = ('C:\\Thesis\\Test_Report_Viewer\\Test.vtestreport')   
              print(fileName)`                                                                                                                                                        The output is > C:\Thesis\Test_Report_Viewer\Test.vtestreport

Comment: why put `()` around the filename string, looks like you're now using `\\`, SyntaxError means you have typed something wrong, use a Hex Editor to see the real content of the file, VSC has an HexEditor extension

Comment: When calling the exe directly, you give the filename as argument. When calling from python, you try to give the file content as argument. Why? Also paths containing a `>` are not valid. Apart from that, everything the @rioV8 has stated is valid

Comment: @rioV8  thanks for your inputs. I have used ´\\´ in place of ´>´ and it worked.